# Windows 7: Scheduling a program start, file open & file save as

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, tableau-api

I need to set up a scheduled job where a .twb file is opened (in Tableau) and then have Tableau save it as an existing .twbx file.

We need to do this because there are limited licenses and it needs to be done at a time when the people with the licenses are not on site.

I know how to create a scheduled task where the program starts with the file as the argument.  But is there a way to then automate a step within a program?  (Or have a batch file that has all of the steps, or some alternative approach to this)

Thank you.

Comment: You would probably need something like winbatch to click GUI windows for you.
http://www.winbatch.com/

Comment: Is this a programming question or something more suited for SuperUser or ServerFault?